# How to make sure a Row {} or Column {} does not contract when an item's visible: property is set to false?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, programming, qml

This is a question about good coding practice with QML:

How can I make sure that a Row {} or Column {} does not contract when one of its Item's visible: property is set to false?

The current work around is poor in that I set the height of the item to 0.0001.

Answer (score 1):

I you need to keep the column size, do not use the `visible` property, prefer to set the Item `opacity` to `0`:

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Column { /* outer column */
      spacing: 10
      Text { text: "Column Element"}
      Column { /* inner column */
        x: 10; y: 10
        spacing: 10
        Rectangle { width: 40; height: 20; color: "red" }
        Rectangle { width: 40; height: 20; color: "green" }
        Rectangle { width: 40; height: 20; color: "blue"; opacity: 0 }
      }
      Text { text: "Row Element" }
      Row { /* inner row */
        spacing: 10
        Rectangle { width: 40; height: 20; color: "red" }
        Rectangle { width: 40; height: 20; color: "green" }
        Rectangle { width: 40; height: 20; color: "blue" }
      }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately in this case; this is not an acceptable solution, as the components visibility will block anything under it from being interacted with. In this case; a flickable. :P

Comment: @Akiva Humm, difficult to figure out what you're trying to achieve here. Could you include the relevant part (including the Flickable) in your question please?

Comment: yah sure http://i.imgur.com/GCsBfma.jpg -- see how these buttons are situated above the flickable here? If I make it transparent, then the flickable can not be flicked if I click on the relavent area.

Comment: What we ended up doing is getting rid of the row, and setting the x manually, although that code was not the prettiest either.

Comment: @Akiva: Could you give us the bzr branch you're working on please? that way we could try other "prettier workarounds"

Comment: lp:~akiva/ubuntu-calendar-app/All-Day-Events-Button